# DATE_DIFF to calculate difference between two dates in BigQuery

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I am trying to work out the difference in seconds between two dates in BigQuery.

The suggested syntax is:

```
SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME "2010-07-07 10:20:00",DATETIME "2008-12-25 15:30:00", SECOND)
```

which works ok.

When I try to use stored fields however, the syntax doesn't work in the same way:

```
with dates as (
SELECT
"2010-07-07 10:20:00" as date1,
 "2008-12-25 15:30:00" as date2
)
SELECT
   DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME (date2), DATETIME (date1), SECOND)
FROM dates
```

I'm sure it's a simple error but would like to know why this isn't working as expected?

Comment: In second query you are using DATE_DIFF instead of DATETIME_DIFF. That might be the reason of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. That was an error - it still doesn't work when using DATETIME_DIFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT "2010-07-07 10:20:00" AS date1, "2008-12-25 15:30:00" AS date2
)
SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP(date2)), DATETIME(TIMESTAMP(date1)), SECOND)
FROM dates
```

Fix is obvious and clearly seen in above code

Another option:

```
#standardSQL
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT "2010-07-07 10:20:00" AS date1, "2008-12-25 15:30:00" AS date2
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(date2), TIMESTAMP(date1), SECOND)
FROM dates
```

Comment: Ah missing TIMESTAMP! Thank you